# Retaining SailsJs Service property value

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I have a service like below:

*SomeService.js*

```
module.exports = {

    property:null,

    foo:function(){

       User.destroy({user_email:user.user_email}).exec(function(error,users){   
           this.property='somevalue'
       });

    }

}
```

When i call this service like below, it does not retain the value of `property` variable.

```
SomeService.foo();
console.log(SomeService.property) //returns null
```

How do i use the Sails service to retain the `property` value? How do i use it like a class? Maybe it's more of a JavaScript question than Sails. I know that the object does not remain same the way i'm using it but is there a way so that i can use the same object for a service?

**UPDATE** : I have updated `foo` and i think the `this` in this case refers to `destroy` construct and not the service.

Comment: Which version of Sails are you using? I checked that in my code and it seems working fine with 0.12.1.

Comment: @Bonanza Its 0.11.5.

Comment: Can you try updating to latest ?

Comment: That way you need to replace 'this' with service name.

Comment: Ok. That seems to work. Thanks. One question though. Does that make it work like a static property?

Comment: It should work like that. I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure 100%.

Comment: For me it works fine.
make sure you are not calling SomeService.foo() asynchronously!

Answer (score 0):

> It's very obvious that you are getting `null` since the function `foo`
>   is calling an **asynchronous method**.

```
foo:function(){
    //the below functions is asynchronous so it is being pushed to event queue.
    //and setting this.property='someValue' becomes asynchronous.
    User.destroy({user_email:user.user_email}).exec(function(error,users){
        this.property='somevalue'
    });
};
```

so while calling:

```
SomeService.foo();//this is asynchronous so does not block next executions.
console.log(SomeService.property)//this is not blocked by above call.
```

### If you wanna test what exactly is happening.Run the following.

```
module.exports = {
    property:null,
    foo:function(){

        User.destroy({user_email:user.user_email}).exec(function(error,users){
            SomeService.property='somevalue';
            console.log("Am i executed first???? Oh no I am the last among them");
        });
    }
};
```

And This:

```
SomeService.foo();
console.log(SomeService.property);
for(var i=2;i<10;i++)
    console.log("I am called at number:",i);
```

So i guess you got the reason why it is happening.